# Is visibility of an SSL certificate for localhost a security threat

Tags: ssl

I'm developing an Angular app and I created a self-signed certificate for **localhost** that I use when serving the app locally with https. I install it as a trusted certificate in Windows on my local PC so that I don't keep getting security prompts when using Chrome.

My question is: Is it very important to keep the details of this development certificate private?

The cert only verifies that localhost is my own PC (what else could it be?), so is visibility of this certificate useful to any malicious outsider?  For example, if it got exposed in a public git repo would that matter?

I'm after a basic level security here, I don't need military-level protection.

UPDATE:

I'm not asking about privacy of ssl certificates and keys in general, but specifically about a certificate for the host "localhost".

For example: I can see how allowing someone to impersonate "drurys.org" would be a security threat.  I would keep those details secret! But what advantage could an outsider gain by trying to impersonate "localhost"?  How can anyone visit "https://localhost/" and the endpoint be anything other than the real local host?

UPDATE 2: So I understand now that there is no harm in adding the certificate for localhost to a public git repository.

What if the private key were leaked and became visible too?  That would allow someone else to use this certificate, but is there a scenario where this would be dangerous?  How could someone use my certificate for "localhost" in a way that would verify https://localhost/ as a request to anything other than the genuine local host?

Comment: No. There is nothing secret about certificates, and it follows immediately that there is nothing secret about certificates for a particular host either.

Comment: If you leak your private key your certificate is worthless. You have to re-key, re-CSR, re-sign, and reinstall the new certificate.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne - my localhost certificate doesn't secure anything. It is just there so I can use https to develop and test on my local PC, so I can mock what happens in the production environments    My question is not _does exposing the details make it worthless_, but _does exposing the details make it dangerous_?

Comment: Leaking the private key makes it both worthless and dangerous, as now the leakee can impersonate that host.

Comment: @Marquis of Lorne - yes exactly.  How does an attacker impersonate localhost?  Calls to https://localhost/ will only ever go to one end point, your own IP address.  How can you pretend that the localhost is not the localhost?

Comment: By having its certificate and private key.

Comment: If an attacker installs my certificate for _localhost_ on their server then he/she is the only person who can access it.  I can't ever get a page from localhost from their machine.  They can't get ever a page from localhost from mine.  Whenever anyone attempts to get a page from localhost they will always get a page served from their own machine.  In what way can an attacker use knowledge of the key impersonate anything?

Comment: @PaulD this is a very good question. I think a lot of guys answer automatically that you shouldn't expose your private key, without thinking too much about it. I also wonder if there is any known attack that somehow uses localhost cert and private key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the localhost certificate on a malicious server will not work because localhost always refers to the current machine.

If your localhost certificate has the certificate authority flag set, exposing your key can pose a security risk. An attacker can sign a certificate for any domain using your certificate as certificate authority. Because the localhost certificate is trusted by your machine, the certificates signed with it will also be trusted. This can be a risk for you; however, the signed certificate will not be a risk in general, as your local host certificate is only trusted by you.

Comment: Finally a useful answer that is addressing the significance of localhost